# Error running App: "Item Not Available"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an iOS application that I developed that runs fine newer iPhones and iPads.

I get this error on a 1st generation iPad running iOS 5.1.1:
"The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store."

The app is distributed by the B2B store and was installed using a coupon code.

5.1.1 is the latest version that will run on a 1st generation iPad.

I double checked the app's settings in itunes connect and it is marked as available in the U.S. store; in fact, that is the only store it is available in.

Other similar apps that I have developed will run fine on the iPad, BUT those apps are built for the public Appstore.  This is why I am pursuing B2B as the problem.

A user reported this problem to me, and I was able to reproduce it easily, so it is not limited to one device.

I cannot find any documentation that this should not work.

How can I get the real reason this is failing?

Is there documentation on minimum version of iOS that supports B2B distribution?

What else should I check?
[image: screen shot showing error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem "magically" went away.

Here is the story of it going away:

I reported it to Apple and after several days they responded that they could not reproduce the problem.

I picked up the iPad 1 and tried to reproduce the problem myself.  I could not reproduce the problem.

I suspect it was something with Apple's servers as I did not change anything on the iPad 1 as all I was doing with it was testing this bug.

I know that I was not nuts for reporting this problem as one of the users of my app reported it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading about custom B2B app distribution recently & found some [links](http://undefinedvalue.com/2012/07/12/distributing-custom-ios-b2b-app). Please have a look at "Submission and Distribution" They mentioned that

```
When the app is approved for sale, your customers purchase redemption codes from the VPP portal. It will not be available in the App Store app or iTunes.
```

May be thats why user is not able to see it in US app store. The [WWDC 2012 session video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) "Building and Distributing Custom B2B Apps for IOS" is worth watching if you are interested in distributing a B2B app. You need Apple ID for watching this video

Also have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843575/how-are-b2b-ios-apps-approved) . This link mentions the steps for B2B app distribution.

Comment: I am not having problems with building and distributing B2B apps in general, just specifically to 1st Generation iPad.  The links you provided are good for a general knowledge, but not for debugging this issue.